# What are the main characters ranks in the Star Trek TV shows?

Tags: star-trek, tv

What are the ranks of the main characters the various Star Trek TV shows (not the movies), e.g.

- ST:TOS
- ST:TAS
- ST:TNG
- ST:DS9
- ST:VOY
- ST:ENT
- ST:DIS
- ST:PIC
- ST:LOW
- ST:PRO

I cannot find a definite source on this, but obviously the likes of Jake, Quark, Seven, Kes, and Neelix are civilians.

Comment: You've asked a very broad question relating to 5 different series, and dozens of characters per show (some of whom get promoted/demoted multiple times). Could you narrow it down to be answerable without having to write a book in the process.

Comment: Note that Quark served on a ship and has a rank and Neelix was the master-captain of his own vessel

Comment: I'm not sure why this is worthy of closure. It's trivially simply to answer *if you know where to look*, but probably quite difficult for a casual fan.

Comment: @Valorum: To be fair, there are a few cases where it's not quite "trivially simple", as e.g. when visual evidence and dialogue contradict one another (presumably, because authors got confused about the ranks themselves). However, it's indeed a minority of characters.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Indeedy. I might start to add some extra info about conflicting ranks (e.g. Miles *"What the hell is his rank?"* O'Brien)

Comment: Ah, [the enigmatic Mr. O’Brien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60546/440). We could do with a tag just for questions about his rank.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. ST:TOS, ST:TAS, ST:TNG, ST:DS9, ST:V, ST:E, ST:D, ST:Pi, ST:LD,ST:Pr... counting more than 5 series.

Comment: True, I'd found the animated versions either unavailable (the old ones) or hard-going (Lower Decks) so mentally didn't count them. @Lexible

Comment: Easily found by looking it up on the Memory Alpha wiki

Comment: think this should at least be scoped to a particular org (ie: Starfleet, etc...)

Comment: @Lexible: honestly— if we're going to refer to shows by impenetrable acronyms, we should at least keep them consistent. I think the last six on your list should be ST:VOY, ST:ENT, ST:DIS, ST:PIC, ST:LOW, ST:PRO.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Given that 95% of all main characters are Starfleet personnel or on secondment to Starfleet, it really goes without saying.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix all in one place?

Comment: @PaulD. Waite Small hill to make a stand on, Paul. :)

Comment: @Lexible: insert inspiring speech about upholding the ideals of the Federation in a broken galaxy from _Discovery_ season 3 here!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite *now* you are talking my language. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Star Trek: The Original Series**

- William Shatner as Captain James T. Kirk
- Leonard Nimoy as Lt. Commander, then Commander Spock
- DeForest Kelley as Lt. Commander Doctor Leonard McCoy
- James Doohan as Lt. Commander, then Commander Montgomery Scott
- George Takei as Lieutenant Hikaru Sulu
- Walter Koenig as Ensign Pavel Chekov (season 2-3)
- Nichelle Nichols as Lieutenant Nyota Uhura
- Majel Barrett as Lieutenant Christine Chapel
- Grace Lee Whitney as Yeoman Janice Rand

**Star Trek: The Animated Series**

As above, plus

- James Doohan as Lieutenant Arex
- Majel Barrett as Lieutenant M'Ress

**The Next Generation cast**

- Patrick Stewart as Captain Jean-Luc Picard
- Jonathan Frakes as Commander William T. Riker
- Brent Spiner as Lt. Commander Data
- LeVar Burton as (J.G), then Lieutenant, then Lt. Commander Geordi La Forge
- Michael Dorn as (J.G), then Lieutenant, then Lt. Commander Worf
- Gates McFadden as Commander Beverly Crusher
- Marina Sirtis as Lt. Commander, then Commander Deanna Troi
- Denise Crosby as Lieutenant Natasha Yar
- Wil Wheaton as Ensign Wesley Crusher
- Diana Muldaur as Commander Katherine Pulaski

**Deep Space Nine cast**

- Avery Brooks as Commander, then Captain Benjamin Sisko
- Nana Visitor as Major, then Colonel (Bajoran Militia rank), and Commander (Starfleet rank) Kira Nerys
- Rene Auberjonois as Constable (note, not a Starfleet rank) Odo
- Michael Dorn as Lt. Commander Worf
- Terry Farrell as Lieutenant Jadzia Dax (season 1-6)
- Alexander Siddig as (J.G), then Lieutenant Julian Bashir
- Aron Eisenberg as Ensign then Lieutenant J.G. Nog
- Colm Meaney as Chief Petty Officer Miles O'Brien
- Nicole de Boer as Lieutenant J.G. Ezri Dax
- Armin Shimerman as Ship's Cook (note, not a Starfleet Rank) Quark
- Cirroc Lofton as Jake Sisko (No rank)

**Star Trek: Voyager**

- Kate Mulgrew as Captain Kathryn Janeway
- Robert Beltran as Commander Chakotay
- Tim Russ as Lieutenant then Lt. Commander Tuvok
- Robert Duncan McNeill as Lieutenant, then Ensign, then Lieutenant Tom Paris
- Roxann Dawson as J.G. Then Lieutenant B'Elanna Torres
- Garrett Wang as Ensign Harry Kim
- Jeri Ryan as Seven of Nine (No rank)
- Robert Picardo as The Doctor (No rank)
- Ethan Phillips as Captain (Note, not a military rank) Neelix
- Jennifer Lien as Kes (No rank)

**Star Trek: Enterprise**

- Scott Bakula as Captain Jonathan Archer
- Jolene Blalock as Sub-Commander, later Commander T'Pol
- Connor Trinneer as Commander Charles Tucker III
- Dominic Keating as Lieutenant Malcolm Reed
- Anthony Montgomery as Ensign Travis Mayweather
- Linda Park as Ensign Hoshi Sato
- John Billingsley as Doctor Phlox (No rank)

**Star Trek: Discovery**

- Sonequa Martin-Green as Commander, then Captain Michael Burnham
- Doug Jones as Lieutenant, then Lt. Commander, then Commander, then Captain Saru
- Shazad Latif as Lieutenant Ash Tyler
- Anthony Rapp as Lieutenant, then Lt. Commander Paul Stamets
- Mary Wiseman as Cadet, then Ensign, then Lieutenant Sylvia Tilly
- Wilson Cruz as Lt. Commander Hugh Culber
- Jason Isaacs as Captain Gabriel Lorca
- Anson Mount as Captain Christopher Pike (season 2)
- Michelle Yeoh as Captain Philippa Georgiou

**Star Trek: Picard**

- Patrick Stewart as Admiral (Ret.) Jean-Luc Picard
- Alison Pill as Agnes Jurati (no rank)
- Isa Briones as Soji Asha (no rank)
- Evan Evagora as Elnor (no rank)
- Michelle Hurd as Commander (Ret.) Raffi Musiker
- Santiago Cabrera as Commander (Ret.) Cristóbal Rios
- Harry Treadaway as Operative (note, not a Starfleet rank) Narek

**Star Trek: Lower Decks**

- Tawny Newsome as Ensign Beckett Mariner
- Jack Quaid as Ensign Brad Boimler
- Noël Wells as Ensign D'Vana Tendi
- Eugene Cordero as Ensign Sam Rutherford
- Dawnn Lewis as Captain Carol Freeman
- Jerry O'Connell as Commander Jack Ransom
- Fred Tatasciore as Lt. Commander Shaxs
- Gillian Vigman as Lt. Commander T'Ana

Note that none of the main characters in ST: Prodigy are ranked. The only Starfleet person in the main cast is a *hologram* of Admiral Janeway.

---

Note that this answer reflects the ["Regular Cast" feature on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Regular_cast).

Note also that the ranks listed above reflect ranks that remained with the character for more than a single episode (e.g. no '*time-skip into the future*' episodes and alternate timelines).

Comment: "Jolene Blalock as Sub-Commander, later Commander T'Pol" - those are ranks from the Vulcan High Command. As it is pointed out for some other characters that their ranks are, e.g., Bajoran Militia ranks, the non-Starfleet rank system might be noted here as well, for the sake of consistency.

Comment: "Aron Eisenberg as Ensign then Lieutenant J.G. Nog" - I'm pretty sure Nog was a cadet for a while, as well.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I was thinking that we'd reflect their Starfleet rank (if any), then any other ranks held if not.

Comment: @Valorum: Indeed, and T'Pol doesn't have a Starfleet rank, either. My point was that if Kira's rank is listed as "Major, then Colonel (Bajoran Militia rank), and Commander (Star Fleet rank)", then I don't see a reason why T'Pol's shouldn't be listed as "Sub-Commander (Vulcan High Command rank), later Commander (Starfleet rank)". But it's a really minor suggestion.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - T'Pol has a Starfleet rank of Commander, as of Stormfront, Part II.

Comment: Montgomery Scott is a Lt Commander in TOS, according to his insignia.

Comment: @MarcWilson - You are, of course, correct.

Comment: @Valorum Re Spock... yes, he's called Lt Commander and later Commander in TOS, but he never wears anything less than two stripes.  In Court Martial, he is explicitly tagged as Lt Cmdr when his record is read out, but he is wearing, again, two stripes.